# Create/Modify Wordpress inbound POST request and forward to external endpoint

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, http-post, wordpress-rest-api

I'm a bit of a noobie with Wordpress and I'd like to know how to handle something forwarding a POST request to an external endpoint:

I've got Google Tag manager ready to send a POST request with a JSON payload to a Wordpress endpoint (or similar), and I need Wordpress to add an Authentication header with an API key to the request and sent over to an external site (example.com/api/xxx). I'd also like the x-forwarded-for header with the IP address of the GTM request to be added too.

I'm unsure how to approach this (either an extension or the rest API) and with both of those I don't know much about WP and the code.

Please let me know if you can point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

N

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: Nothing yet unfortunately. Temporarily I just set up another endpoint on a different server on a subdomain and that's handling this